# Setting up push on Android with parse

Tags: android, parsing, push

I wanted to get my Application ready for push with parse but this
is what I got:
[image]

It compiles when I erase this line, but also doesnt receive push's from Parse.com:
`PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, ActivityAppLaunch.class);`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you set `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`
in AndroidManifest.xml to allow PushRouter to get access?